# how to remove title from DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using `DialogFragment` in my project and I'am disabling the Title using

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but my dialog has become crooked. I want to leave the dialog as it is and just remove Title. How can I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="#ff2d35ff">


     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#ff6cff23">

         <LinearLayout
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="ItemName"
                 android:id="@+id/itemName"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#ffd861ff"/>

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="ItemPrice"
                 android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#ff2ff8ff"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:id="@+id/itemImage"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="some test"
         android:id="@+id/textView9"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#ffffff2c">

         <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="-"
             android:id="@+id/itemMinus"
             />

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="1"
             android:id="@+id/textView11"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

         <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="+"
             android:id="@+id/itemPlus"/>
     </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal">

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/itemAdd"
         android:src="@drawable/positive"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/itemCancel"
         android:src="@drawable/negative"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I realized that when I remove Title dialog can not found `match_parent`

Comment: Are you calling getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in onCreateDialog or onCreateView?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you must override onCreateDialog method in your dialogfragment class.

```
@Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
      root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
      dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      dialog.setContentView(root);
      dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
      dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

      return dialog;
   }
```

Comment: this helped! I just changed MATCH_PARENT> WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: Yes, I checked thoroughly and note. no doubt), and thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I usually override onCreate in my `DialogFragment`'s subclass and call `setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
}
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle(int,%20int)) you can find the documentation for `setStyle`. The documentation for `STYLE_NO_TITLE` says:

> Style for setStyle(int, int): don't include a title area.

Comment: yes it works too. but my dialog still displayed crooked, after I clean Tittle.

Comment: can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: this is what I want to see http://joxi.ru/V2VGo47FML7PAv
this is what I get http://joxi.ru/nAyegk1FVvEWAZ

Comment: first thing, the two textviews on top. Change for both  android:layout_width="wrap_content" to  android:layout_width="0dp". The weight takes care of it, and run it again

Comment: you should specify weight then only it will align

Answer (score 0):

You can implement is simpler way like below code -

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
```

or

`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,       android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);`